# Getting 404 on main using redirectmatch

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Using

```
  RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ /$1
```

To redirect all incoming trafic from .html url's from google after stripping them, Everything works now exept the www.domain.com get's redirected

Checked link: http://www.url.se

Type of redirect: 301 Moved Permanently
Redirected to: http://www.url.se//index

Answer (score 0):

`index.html` is likely the default in your DirectoryIndex and also matches on `www.url.se`.
Replace the RedirectMatch rule with the rule below in your .htaccess file to fix

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect all html file in /cat/ to just / directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cat/(.+)\.html$ 
RewriteRule . /%1/ [L,R=301]

#apply the next rule for any file except index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thx, Did solve it, The only thing is that i now when getting a 404 it keeps re-loading

Comment: What do you mean by `reloading`: an infinite 301 redirect?

Comment: Also getting it on

 url/cat/art but not on one the one's that are url/art

Comment: Can you give me an example of the request url and the url that it redirects to in infinite loop?

Comment: Now it works, so some cache left. 

On more question, The website also have som links inc that is url.se/cat/article.html i want to 301 redirect them to  url.se/article/

Comment: Am very thankful.   I don't work though :/  It strips ".html" but thats it, the cat is still their, Did also try changing the cat to * and the real category url but did just get error on that